# PC doesnt do anything except spin fans on startup

Tags: boot, bios, motherboard, power-supply, gpu

I have this PC that I use as a server:

```
Atermiter x99 chinese mobo
Xeon e5 2667 v4 cpu
4x8gb ram (non ecc)
Seasonic 430w psu
Chinese nvme ssd, kingston ssd, 1tb hdd
Hd 4670 gpu
```

When I press the power button these things happen:

- the fans spin up
- no beeps
- no display

I think the keyboard inputs don't register

I don't think it even boots into the bios, as when I press Esc to exit bios, it doesn't boot into Ubuntu.

Some backstory:

I swapped out the old Chinese PSU to a new one. I also installed a new SSD and HDD. I took out some front panel stuff as I don't need those. When I plugged in the PC to test it I saw that it didn't connect to my router. so I put the 4670 GPU into it to see that is going on. it worked perfectly. i took out the GPU again and again, it didn't connect to the router and now it started beeping. 1 short beep, one longer strange sounding and 5 short beeps.

I put back the GPU - now it did the beeps again even with the GPU and no display. so i disconnected power and did a CMOS reset and shorted the bios chip (1 and 8 pins) and shorted the CMOS battery slot, took out the ram and did a jumper reset and started the PC up. no beeps strangely. I put the ram back in, no beeps still, but nothing happens. I don't get a display, doesn't connect to router (so it didn't boot into Ubuntu) and my inputs don't register. I put a 2070 into it for testing. still no display, but an led turned on on the GPU.

I think I might have shorted the wrong pins on the bios chip. It used to work fine before now even without a GPU as I used to just ssh into the machine.

Please help as I'm realllllly at a loss of ideas. Thanks you!!!

Comment: If I have this right, after removing the RAM it doesn't beep? If that's the case, it's really sounding like a bad motherboard. You could try doing what's called a "cold boot" and see if that helps.

Comment: @TechLoom Exactly, no beeps without ram. what is a cold boot?

Comment: @TechLoom If i take it to a repair shop, do you think they will be able to do something?

Comment: @TechLoom Yes i have done a cold boot already, and still nothing.

Comment: A repair shop may have some more tools to confirm that the motherboard is bad. But from what you have shared, my guess is the motherboard is having issues.

Comment: @TechLoom okay post here what they say after it take it there